# Enrichment of positive cases within paired data

Tags: biostatistics, contingency-tables, mcnemar-test

I have analyzed 47 cancer samples from tissue and blood. In the tissue 40 are positive for a virus and in the blood 8 are positive for the virus Importantly, these 8 are the same patients that are positive in the tissue. How would you test if there is a higher number of positive blood samples than expected by chance? `mcnemar.test`? `prop.test`?

Something like this? But it does not considered that the blood-positive are the same individual as tissue-positive?

```
tissue_positive <- 40
blood_positive <- 8
total_samples <- 47

expected_proportion <- tissue_positive / total_samples

observed_proportion <- blood_positive / total_samples

result <- prop.test(blood_positive, total_samples, 
                    p = expected_proportion, alternative = "greater")

print(result)
```